# Problem with ShareLaTeX

Tags: errors

I have a problem using [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/) with a template for a thesis. I did not change the template at all, compiling it on my computer worked properly. However, if I compile the template on ShareLaTeX I get the following error message:

```
    ! Emergency stop.
<*> Header.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 18022 strings out of 493109
 345106 string characters out of 6135010
 450499 words of memory out of 5000000
 21311 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4702 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 45i,1n,52p,10373b,87s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

---

Does anyone know what the mistake could be?

Log file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=06314292072988428117

The file `header.tex`:

```
% header.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,ngerman,color]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,top=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[german,english]{babel}

\usepackage{stackengine} %\belowbaseline
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,subfigure}

% Nummerierung in align* durch \numberthis
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}


% Theorem-Umgebungen
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

% Korrekte Darstellung der Umlaute
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Algorithmen
\usepackage[plain,chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\usepackage{enumerate}

%Querformat
\usepackage[asdfclockwise]{rotating}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}

%Center Verbatim
\usepackage{fancyvrb}


% Bibtex deutsch
\usepackage{bibgerm}
%\usepackage{natbib} % citet, citep

% URLs
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\urlstyle{same}
%\usepackage{url}

% Caption Packet
\usepackage[margin=0pt,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
% Gliederung einstellen
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

% Tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
%\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,matrix,positioning}
%\usetikzlibrary {positioning}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
%\usepgflibrary{patterns}
%\usepgflibrary[patterns]
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

% PGF-Plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}


% Euro
\usepackage{textcomp}

% Math
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*\euler{\mathrm{e}}

% Farben
\definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0,0}
\definecolor{green}{rgb}{0,1,0}
\definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}

\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0,1,1}
\definecolor{magenta}{rgb}{1,0,1}

\definecolor{violet}{rgb}{0.5,0,1}

\definecolor{tudogreen}{rgb}{0.52,0.72,0.09}
\definecolor{tudolight}{rgb}{0.91,0.97,0.76}

% Theorem-Optionen %
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremstyle{change}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{satz}[theorem]{Satz}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{korollar}[theorem]{Korollar}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
% Ohne Numerierung
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\renewtheorem{theorem*}{Theorem}
\renewtheorem{satz*}{Satz}
\renewtheorem{lemma*}{Lemma}
\renewtheorem{korollar*}{Korollar}
\renewtheorem{proposition*}{Proposition}
% Definitionen mit \upshape
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremstyle{change}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\renewtheorem{definition*}{Definition}
% Kursive Schrift
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}
\newtheorem{konvention}{Konvention}
\newtheorem{bezeichnung}{Bezeichnung}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\Box}}
\newtheorem{beweis}{Beweis}
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremstyle{change}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
\newtheorem{bemerkung}[theorem]{Bemerkung}
\newtheorem{beobachtung}[theorem]{Beobachtung}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\diamond}}
\newtheorem{beispiel}[theorem]{Beispiel}
%\theoremsymbol{}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\renewtheorem{bemerkung*}{Bemerkung}
\renewtheorem{beispiel*}{Beispiel}
\renewtheorem{problem*}{Problem}

% Algorithmen anpassen %
\renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textit{Eingabe:}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textit{Ausgabe:}}
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithmus}
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Algorithmenverzeichnis}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\color{grau}{// #1}}

% Zeilenabstand einstellen %
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.00}
% Floating-Umgebungen anpassen %
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.9}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.8}
% Abkuerzungen richtig formatieren %
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\vgl}{vgl.\@\xspace} 
\newcommand{\zB}{z.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}\nolinebreak[4]B.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\bzw}{bzw.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\dahe}{d.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}h.\nolinebreak[4]\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\etc}{etc.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\evtl}{evtl.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\ggf}{ggf.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\bzgl}{bzgl.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\so}{s.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}\nolinebreak[4]o.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\iA}{i.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}\nolinebreak[4]A.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\sa}{s.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}\nolinebreak[4]a.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\su}{s.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}\nolinebreak[4]u.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\ua}{u.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}\nolinebreak[4]a.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\og}{o.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}\nolinebreak[4]g.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\oBdA}{o.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}\nolinebreak[4]B.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}d.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}A.\@\xspace}
\newcommand{\OBdA}{O.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}\nolinebreak[4]B.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}d.\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{0.125em}A.\@\xspace}

% Leere Seite ohne Seitennummer, naechste Seite rechts
\newcommand{\blankpage}{
 \clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
}

% Keine einzelnen Zeilen beim Anfang eines Abschnitts (Schusterjungen)
\clubpenalty = 10000
% Keine einzelnen Zeilen am Ende eines Abschnitts (Hurenkinder)
\widowpenalty = 10000 \displaywidowpenalty = 10000
% EOF


%pgfplot-styles
\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={thick, smooth, mark size = 3pt}}
\pgfplotsset{barstyle/.style={black}}

\pgfplotsset{styleBWA/.style={mystyle, color=red, mark=x}}
\pgfplotsset{styleBWAedit/.style={mystyle, color=orange, mark=+}}
\pgfplotsset{styleBWAsw/.style={mystyle, color=orange!60!black, mark=asterisk}}
\pgfplotsset{styleBowtie/.style={mystyle, color=blue, mark=star}}
\pgfplotsset{styleVATRAM/.style={mystyle, color=green, mark=Mercedes star}}
\pgfplotsset{styleVATRAMnovar/.style={mystyle, color=green!75!cyan!50!black, mark=Mercedes star flipped}}
\pgfplotsset{styleMRSfast/.style={mystyle, color=cyan, mark=|}}

\pgfplotsset{barstyleBWA/.style={barstyle, fill=red}}
\pgfplotsset{barstyleBWAedit/.style={barstyle, fill=orange}}
\pgfplotsset{barstyleBWAsw/.style={barstyle, fill=orange!60!black}}
\pgfplotsset{barstyleBowtie/.style={barstyle, fill=blue}}
\pgfplotsset{barstyleVATRAM/.style={barstyle, fill=green}}
\pgfplotsset{barstyleVATRAMnovar/.style={barstyle, fill=green!75!cyan!50!black}}
\pgfplotsset{barstyleMRSfast/.style={barstyle, fill=cyan}}
\pgfplotsset{barstyleRazer/.style={barstyle, fill=black!35!white}}
\pgfplotsset{barstyleRazerRabema/.style={barstyle, fill=black!65!white}}
```

Comment: Your error says `job aborted, no legal \end found`, did you properly end the document using `\end{document}`?

Comment: What template are you using? Does it compile unchanged or did you change stuff and made the error occur?

Comment: Can you link to `header.tex`?

Comment: Word of advice: Get another template.

Comment: The uploaded file does not show the behaviour described.